# Is standard apache installation on localhost not visible outside the localhost?

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, localhost

I'ḿ new to Ubuntu and installed apache2, php and mysql referring to these instructions:
[Setting up VPS Ubuntu Server 14 04 LTS WordPress Lamp Linux, Apache2, MySQL, PHP - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dr2BBBngGg)

As far as I know from Windows, default XAMPP installation, for example, runs only on localhost, not on the internet.

I assume the same for this installation.

I tried from another computer to connect to my ip-adress but it was not possible.

So everything is fine now, right?

Comment: find your ip address with `ifconfig` and check? If you haven't done any port forwarding. Then it will only be visible on the local network. (ie `192.168.0.xxx`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to access it from anywhere you need a static ip, else you can only find it from local host.

You can set up a static ip for free with this http://www.noip.com/ then you access your pc by its ip.